# stop scrolling while moving div element javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar, mouse

i got problem with scrollbar, when im trying to move div element to the bottom of the screen (using onmousedown,onmousemove,onmouseup functions) scrollbar starts scrolling down ,it looks like overflow,how to make scrollbar not moving down while i moving elements to the bottom and scrolling only if there is overflow with text or sth like that?? Any Idea??

Answer (score 0):

toggle a CSS class on `<html>` and `<body>` that sets the `overflow` property to `hidden` while moving your elements.

Not too sure how your implementation looks, but something along these lines:

#### CSS

```
.whileMoving { 
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

#### Javascript

```
var foo  = document.getElementById('yourDiv'), 
    html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0],
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

foo.addEventListener('onmousedown', function(){
    body.className = "whileMoving";
    html.className = "whileMoving";
},false);

// Then, remove the class on mouse up.

foo.addEventListener('onmouseup', function(){
    body.className = "";
    html.className = "";
},false);
```